# snmpwalk from remote results in timeout

Tags: fedora, snmp

I have three devices (`A`,`B`,`C`) in my LAN all running snmpd. Apart from the community string they all have the same snmpd configuration. They can all run `snmpwalk` to the other devices except when trying to connect to Device `C`.

Device `C` when calling itself, either through `127.0.0.1` or by it's `<LAN-IP>` address also works.

```
snmpwalk -v 2c -c <community-string> 127.0.0.1 # OK
snmpwalk -v 2c -c <community-string> <LAN-IP>  # OK
```

When Device `A` or `B` tries to connect to Device `C`, a timeout error occurs

```
snmpwalk -v 2c -c <community-string> <DEVICE-C-LAN-IP>
Timeout: No Response from <DEVICE-C-LAN-IP>
```

When run with debugging on, I can see 6 blocks of identical lines similar to this:

```
Sending 54 bytes to UDP: [<DEVICE-C-LAN-IP>]:161->[0.0.0.0]:0
...
0048: 06 01 02 01  05 00                                    ......
```

Which eventually ends with

```
Timeout: No Response from <DEVICE-C-LAN-IP>
```

Device `C` does have `selinux` which I've temporarily disabled with `setenforce 0`.

There are also no firewall rules on Device `C` (`iptables -L`) that I can see.

The only thing strange that I can see, is when calling `service snmpd status` on Device `C`

```
● snmpd.service - Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP) Daemon.
...

Feb 22 09:47:16 fedora-box systemd[1]: Starting Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP) Daemon....
Feb 22 09:47:16 fedora-box snmpd[25707]: Can't find directory of RPM packages
Feb 22 09:47:16 fedora-box snmpd[25707]: NET-SNMP version 5.9
Feb 22 09:47:16 fedora-box systemd[1]: Started Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP) Daemon..
```

So service is up, but has a simple warning: `Can't find directory of RPM packages`. Not sure if that is the culprit or not.

Any help to track this down would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

**Update**

**Debugging**

```
snmpwalk -D ALL
```

I can make out 6 requests (nothing strange) and the following at the end

```
trace: snmp_synch_input(): snmp_client.c, 178:
snmp_synch: Response (ReqID: 366399853 - Cmd 161)
trace: snmp_synch_input(): snmp_client.c, 231:
snmp_synch: status = 2 errno = -24
Timeout: No Response from 192.168.70.10
trace: netsnmp_transport_cache_remove(): snmp_transport.c, 1237:
transport:cache:close: 0x55d19b3ef8e0
trace: _tc_find_transport(): snmp_transport.c, 1210:
transport:cache:find_transport: 0x55d19b3ef8e0
trace: netsnmp_transport_cache_remove(): snmp_transport.c, 1245:
transport:cache:close: 0x55d19b3ef8e0 not found in cache
```

**netstat**

```
netstat -ltup | grep snmp
tcp        0      0 localhost:smux          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2446/snmpd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:snmp            0.0.0.0:*                           2446/snmpd
```

**nmap**

```
# nmap -v <DEVICE-C-LAN-IP>
Nmap scan report for device-c-hostname (<DEVICE-C-LAN-IP>)
Host is up (0.00069s latency).
Not shown: 998 filtered ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
9090/tcp open  zeus-admin
```

==========

**Environment**

- Device A: Ubuntu 20.04
- Device B: CentOS 7 (based)
- Device C: Fedora 33

**snmpd.conf**

```
agentAddress  udp:161
rocommunity <community-string> 127.0.0.1
rocommunity <community-string> <LAN-SUB-NET>/24
```

Comment: Any difference in network activity as viewed, by say, wireshark?

Comment: Where successful (local), for every `get-next-request`, there's a `get-response`. However, where it fails (remote), there are 6 `get-next-request` without any responses

Comment: Wireshark capture on Device `C`: https://imgur.com/a/cGMy6Lr

Comment: Perhaps setting log priority to `LOG_DEBUG` might reveal the problem.  I also wonder if this is an authorization issue - I see lots of settings in the default configuration file.

Comment: @rickhg12hs I've added (some) debugging to the question. Nothing there that pops out at me as being the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Urghh. `firewalld` was installed and enabled by default on Fedora 33.

Running `nmap` to device `C` was the pointer that I needed to see something was up.

So either disable the firewall if you're on an internal network. Or setup some rules for `firewalld` to play with.